# regroup similar element in array angular 4

Tags: javascript

I want to find the similair element in an array(the same fruit) and calculate the total quantity, for example, I have this list:

```
let array = [
  {
    fruit: "Apple",
    quantity: "2",
  },
  {
    fruit: "Banane",
    quantity: "1",
  },
  {
    fruit: "Kiwi",
    quantity: "5", 
  },
  {
    fruit: "Banane",
    quantity: "2",
  },
  {
    fruit: "Apple",
    quantity: "6",
  },
  {
    fruit: "Ananas",
    quantity: "10",
  },
  {
    fruit: "Apple",
    quantity: "3",
  }
];
```

The list shoudn't have a similair element(fruit) with different quantity, it shoud be like this:

```
array = [
  {
    fruit: "Apple",
    quantity: "11",
  },
  {
    fruit: "Banane",
    quantity: "3",
  },
  {
    fruit: "Kiwi",
    quantity: "5", 
  },
  {
    fruit: "Ananas",
    quantity: "10",
  }
]
```

I tried to use filter, indexOf to get the element with the same fruit value, but I didn't succeed. What's the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet of code that does what you want, the comments explain every bit.

```
const counts = {} // This will keep track of the counts of each fruit as key value pair
array.forEach(element => {
  if(counts[element.fruit] !== undefined) { // This means that the current fruit have been found before 
    return counts[element.fruit] += Number(element.quantity); // Add the quantity of the current fruit element to the overall summation
  }
  // If the return statement above was not executed, it means that we are seeing the the fruit for the first time
  counts[element.fruit] = Number(element.quantity);
  // Initialize an entry for it in the summations object above, initally set to the current elements quantity
});

// Map the object to become an array again, and overwrite the original array with it if that's desired
array = Object.keys(counts).map(fruit => ({fruit, quantity: counts[fruit]}));
```